# Where to save PHP/MySQL file in WAMP or XWAMP server?

Tags: php

Please tell me where should I save `mysqli_connect.php` file (used to connect to the database) if I use WAMP or XWAMP server, also can you describe to me the directory structure and also explain to me where to save normal PHP file (which contains code functionality)?

Comment: not sure if I got question correctly but `[xampp_root_directory]/htdocs/` here you can put all of your php files

Comment: Its something like C:\xampp\htdocs  if your xampp is on  C drive

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server) for XAMP server and [This](http://breakthesecurity.cysecurity.org/2011/07/how-to-run-php-files-using-wamp-server.html) fro wamp server .

Answer (score 3):

**For WAMP server**

Assume you installed WAMP in C Drive.
Go to: `C:\wamp\www\[your project name folder]\mysqli_connect.php`

Eample:`C:\wamp\www\myProject\mysqli_connect.php`

---

**for XAMPP sever:**

Assume you installed xampp in C Drive.
Go to: `C:\xampp\htdocs\[your project name folder]\mysqli_connect.php`

Example:`C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\mysqli_connect.php`

Answer (score 0):

For wamp server, the following:

```
C:\wamp\www\mysqli_connect.php
```

Or

```
C:\wamp\www\your_directory\mysqli_connect.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In WAMP you have path like c:/wamp/www, in www folder you can create 'project' folder in which you should put all your code. In that folder you are putting your code as well as database code(for connecting to db for example).

In the end you have c:/wamp/www/project and there is your code.

If you want to make some new project called foobar than create folder in www and put code in it(c:/wamp/www/foobar).